# Why does sending to channel is blocked when a panic occurs?

Tags: go

I am going to show a simple compilable code snipped where I get weird behaviour: after I intentionally cause a panic in `processData` (because I pass nil-pointer) the sending to channel `l.done` is blocked!

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Loop struct {
    done chan struct{}
}

type Result struct {
    ID string
}

func NewLoop() *Loop {
    return &Loop{
        done: make(chan struct{}),
    }
}

func (l *Loop) StartAsync(ctx context.Context) {
    go func() {
        defer func() {
            l.done <- struct{}{} // BLOCKED! But I allocated it in NewLoop ctor
            fmt.Sprintf("done")
        }()
        for {
            /**/
            var data *Result
            l.processData(ctx, data) // passed nil
        }
    }()
}

func (l *Loop) processData(ctx context.Context, data *Result) {
    _ = fmt.Sprintf("%s", data.ID) // intentional panic - OK
}
func main() {
    l := NewLoop()
    l.StartAsync(context.Background())
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
}
```

I can `recover()` a panic before sending to channel and I get correct error message.
What does happen with channel? It it was closed, I would get panic on sending to closed channel

Comment: It's blocking because there isn't anything receiving from the channel. Both receive & 
 send operation on a channel will block if there's only one of them. Basically `c := new(chan struct{})`; and then `c<-struct{}{}` will block forever unless there is another goroutine that receives from the channel, i.e. `<-c`. That's how channels are supposed to behave. That's how the languages specification defines their behaviour. Nothing weird here.

Comment: agree, so declare a buffered channel, as follows :`done: make(chan struct{}, 1),`

Comment: @mkopriva, very interesting. Can you add an answer and I'll mark it as resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's blocking because there isn't anything receiving from the channel. Both the receive & the send operations on an *initialized* and *unbuffered* channel will block indefinitely if the opposite operation is missing. I.e. a send to a channel will block until another goroutine receives from that channel, and, likewise, a receive from a channel will block until another goroutine sends to that channel.

So basically

```golang
done := new(chan struct{})
done<-struct{}{}
```

will block forever unless there is another goroutine that receives from the channel, i.e. `<-done`. That's how channels are supposed to behave. That's how the languages specification defines their behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

*about the possible fixes :*

given the name of your channel, you may want to run `close(l.done)` rather than `l.done <- struct{}{}`.

- using a buffered channel and `l.done <- struct{}{}` on completion : only *one* call to `<-l.done` will be unblocked.

Suppose you have some code looking like :

```
l := NewLoop()

go func(){
    <-l.done
    closeLoggers()
}()

go func(){
    <-l.done
    closeDatabase()
}()
```

sending one item on the `done` channel will make that only one consumer will receive it, and in the above example only one of the two actions will be triggered when the loop completes.

- using `close(l.done)` : once a channel is closed *all* calls to receive from it will proceed.

In the above example, all actions will proceed.

As a side note: there is no need for a buffer if you use a channel only for its "open/closed" state.